# MAMP Pro: Setting up a host with a network disk location

Tags: apache, mamp, hosts

So I love it that MAMP Pro makes it super easy to set up hosts and access logs and stuff. But I am now working at a location where all of the local copies of websites are on a shared server, e.g. /Volumes/Server/Websites/MyAwesomeWebsite.

Unfortunately, when I try to select a folder on the server, all the folders are greyed out. And when I type the path in manually and restart Apache, I get the message:

"Some hosts have an invalid disk location. These hosts won't be reachable if you start Apache now."

There's really no point in using MAMP Pro if I can't set hosts up on the shared server... any ideas? Or am I gonna have to stop being lazy and edit the virtual hosts by hand from now on?

Comment: If I set it anyway and then try to open the site, it gives me a 403 Forbidden. If I click the Permissions button in MAMP, it says the group is "staff" (vs. "admin" on the disk locations in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to get it to work, so I rolled back from MAMP Pro to MAMP and started editing the virtual host files by hand. It's actually not bad at all, I put a shortcut in my dock that launches both files in BBEdit, so adding new virtual hosts is still quick and easy.